# NoHttpResponseException 443 failed to respond error on different computer/network

Tags: jmeter

I've got a strange problem. I run my JMeter test on one computer/network and my test runs perfectly all the time. Single thread, multithread, it runs with no errors. I then run the same test on a different computer/network and I'm getting the below error. The error happens at random steps and not the same step each time.

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: home-env-c.t1cloud.com:443 failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:930)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:641)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1281)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1270)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've searched for the error and added these two lines to user.properties but it didn't work:

```
 httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
 http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
```

Comment: No certificates or whitelisting. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the "other" computer has different (better) hardware specifications it might be the case you're delivering more load than your server can handle so it looks like to be a [bottleneck](https://qa-platforms.com/detecting-bottlenecks-performance-testing/)

Inspect how many requests per second you produce in both cases, it can be done by looking at [Server Hits per Seconds](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond) or [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond) charts or by simply looking into how many requests in the given period JMeter was able to make.

If it appears that the "other" computer produces more load than you expect/need you can slow it down using JMeter Timers in general and [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) in particular.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dmitri. The other computer is actually a slower one so not sure what is going on. I'm playing around with timers to see if I get a different result.

Comment: I misunderstood what you said. What you're saying makes sense. The slower computer is putting less load through (slower load) hence it is not erroring. The other computer is faster and is pumping more through and hence the errors. I put a thread level constant timer of 5 seconds to slow the load and it worked perfectly. We have found a performance issue! Thanks